# How can I add a Flask/WTForms SelectField to my HTML?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am building a form in my Flask app and want the users to be able to select an option from a `<select>` menu.

For example:

```
<select>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Pineapple</option>
</select>
```

My current "HTML" for this is

```
<form action="{{ url_for('contact') }}" method=post>
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

  {{ form.name.label }}
  {{ form.name }}

  {{ form.company.label }}
  {{ form.company }}

  {{ form.email.label }}
  {{ form.email }}

  {{ form.phone.label }}
  {{ form.phone }}

  {{ form.message.label }}
  {{ form.message }}

  {{ form.submit }}
</form>
```

My Python Class for this form is:

```
class ContactForm(Form):
    partner_type = SelectField(
        u'Industry Type',
        choices = [('Software', 'software'), ('Sales', 'sales')]
    )
    name = TextField("Name", [validators.Required("Please enter your full name.")])
    email = TextField("Email", [validators.Required("Please enter a valid email i.e. you@yourdomain.com"), validators.Email()])
    phone = TextField("Phone", [validators.Required("Please enter a valid phone number.")])
    company = TextField("Company", [validators.Required("Please enter your company name.")])
    message = TextAreaField("Message", [validators.Required("Please include a message regarding this submission.")])
    submit = SubmitField("Send")
```

This all works great for text fields and submit button but I can't seem to figure out how to properly render the `<select>` options to the form. I tried following the syntax above by doing:

```
{{ form.industry_type.label }}
{{ form.industry_type }}
```

but that didn't work. It just added the label and no drop down selector. Is there a proper way to add this to the DOM? The options are static, preset options, so there's nothing dynamic or complex about the list I am trying to render.

Thanks for the help. I am very new to Python so I am still figuring a lot of things out.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using:

```
{{ form.partner_type.label }}
{{ form.partner_type }}
```

instead of:

```
{{ form.industry_type.label }}
{{ form.industry_type }}
```

The field name in the form is the variable name it is assigned to, not the label in the constructor of the SelectField.